# FirebaseObjectObservable in Angular not displaying returned data

Tags: angular, firebase

I have sibling components 1) a todo list, and 2) a workspace to complete the task. These components have a shared data service that I'm trying to use to transfer the data on the todo list to be the header of the workspace to be completed. The issue is that the data expected to binded with string interpolation isn't being binded. I can see it in my console log and acts as if it's there when using *ngIf="todo" in the wrapping "Div". When I use *ngIf="!todo" it disappears as I would expect.

Help in figuring out why the hell the data isn't binding would be much appreciated!

**todo-list.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable, 
AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

import {Todo} from './todo-list.model';


@Injectable()
export class TodoListService {

private basePath: string = '/todoList';
private baseUrl: string;

todoList: FirebaseListObservable<Todo[]> = null; 
todo: FirebaseObjectObservable<Todo>= null; 

constructor(
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,) 
    { this.todoList = db.list('/todoList');}

getTodosList(query = {}): FirebaseListObservable<Todo[]> {
    this.todoList = this.db.list(this.basePath, {
        query: query
    });
    return this.todoList

}

// Return a single observable item
getTodo(key: string): FirebaseObjectObservable<Todo> {
    const itemPath = `${this.basePath}/${key}`;
    this.todo = this.db.object(itemPath)

    return this.todo
}

createTodo(todo: Todo): void {
    this.todoList.push(todo)
        // .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
}
// Update an existing item
updateTodo(key: string, value: any): void {
    this.todoList.update(key, value)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
}
// Deletes a single item
deleteTodo(key: string): void {
    this.todoList.remove(key)
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
}
// Deletes the entire list of items
deleteAll(): void {
    this.todoList.remove()
        .catch(error => this.handleError(error))
}

// Default error handling for all actions
private handleError(error) {
    console.log(error)
}

}
```

**todo-workspace.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, ParamMap } from "@angular/router";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "angularfire2/database";
import { FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable,         
AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database-deprecated";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


import { Todo } from './../shared/todo-list.model'

import { TodoListService } from './../shared/todo-list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'aurora-todo-workspace',
  templateUrl: './todo-workspace.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo-workspace.component.css']
})
export class TodoWorkspaceComponent implements OnInit{

  todo: any[]=[]; 

  constructor(
    private todoListService: TodoListService,
    private location: Location,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>     
  this.todoListService.getTodo(params.get('id')))
      .subscribe(todo => console.log(todo), 
      err => console.error(err),
  );
}

  onStreamRefreshClick() {
      return null
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

**todo-workspace.component.html**

```
<div class="workspace-container">
  <!--*ngIf="loggedIn$ | async"-->
  <div class="card workspace-container">
    <div class="card-block k-form">
      <button kendoButton [primary]="true" [icon]="'arrow-left'" 
 (click)="goBack()">Back to Dashboard</button>
  <button class="refresh-btn" kendoButton 
(click)="onStreamRefreshClick($event)" [icon]="'refresh'" 
 [look]="'outline'"></button>
  <button class="sign-btn" kendoButton (click)="signSubmit()" 
[primary]="true">Sign & Submit</button>
  <fieldset *ngIf="todo">
    <legend>
      Workspace for {{ todo.firstName }} {{ todo.lastName }} | {{ 
todo.type }} | {{todo.date | kendoDate: 'MM/dd'}}
      @ {{ todo.time | kendoDate:'hh:mm a' }} | {{ todo.where }} | {{ 
todo.why }}
    </legend>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

Just had to do the following refactoring and was good in todo-workshop.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
this.route.params
  .map(params => params ['id'])
  .subscribe((id) => {
    this.todoListService
      .getTodo(id)
      .subscribe( todo => this.todo = todo);

  });
}
```